# How to create a plot with the negative values of a noisy signal?

Tags: matlab

So I have to generate a cos fuction from 0 to 2 pi with added gaussian noise with zero mean and standard deviation of .5 Then I have to create different plots for:

a) the signal with noise and the signal without the noise

This I've already done:

```
clear
close all
% Plot cos function from 0 to 2 pi
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000);
y1 = cos(x);
noise =  .3*randn(1,1000);
prob1a = y1 + noise;
figure
plot(x, y1, x, prob1a)
```

b) plot the negative values of the noisy signal
c) plot the positive values of the noisy signal

I need help with parts b and c.

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
figure()
pos_noise = noise;
pos_noise(pos_noise < 0) = 0;
plot(x, pos_noise)
hold all
neg_noise = noise;
neg_noise(neg_noise > 0) = 0;
plot(x, neg_noise)
```

[image]